# Is it possible to get rid of the ChildWindow animation is Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, childwindow

In my opinion, the animation is too long and too "jumpy" - I'd like to remove it or make it more subtle. Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to re-template the ChildWindow. Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833070%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) so you can copy the default template and make your desired changes to the animation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the full recipe:

1. Extract the Child Window Template. I like to use Blend for this: create an empty project of the same type as your target project, put a child window directly to the main page. Select Edit Template->Edit a copy... Blend creates a style for the ChildWindow.
2. In your target project, add a new "Silverlight Resource Dictionary". name it "ChildWindowResources". Copy the entire style from the Blend project to the ChildWindowResources.xaml. Remove the "x:Key="ChildWindowStyle1" from the copied style.
3. In your target's project App.xaml, add the "ResourceDictionary" section thet looks like this:

-

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary 
Source="/MyApp;component/ChildWindowResources.xaml"/>                
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Now you can edit the template and comment out these pesky animation sections under VisualState x:Name="Open" and VisualState x:Name="Closed"